# how to get debian package from the installed binary

Tags: 14.04, debian, debian-installer

I have installed some utility by `apt-get install crash/kdump`.  Now I want to get the debian package for the installed one. How should I get it? I hope some dpkg commands available to get those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the `.deb` package file, you can find it in `/var/cache/apt/archives` providing you have not cleared your apt cache.

You could download the package to your current directory using `apt-get download <pkgname>` or `sudo apt-get install -d <pkgname>` to save it to `/var/cache/apt/archives` without actually installing.

Comment: thanks mcchots i could find in /var/cache/apt/archives but if i cleared cache it wont be available right? so is there any dpkg command to get debian from installed binary

Comment: I don't think there is a way to recreate the package from an install. You could download it using `apt-get download <pkgname>`